# What is "multiple" myeloma?

Tags: human-biology, cancer, pathology, terminology, hematology

> Multiple myeloma, commonly referred to as myeloma, is a cancer of the plasma cells found in the bone marrow.([source](http://myeloma.ca/en/about-multiple-myeloma/what-is-myeloma))

Is there any significance in calling myeloma as "**MULTIPLE**" myeloma?

Comment: Any reason for downvote? what sort of attempt should I show in this question if I am unable to it by googling?

Comment: You often claim to have googled something but found nothing. Yet, it's that very attempt to find an answer that would make your questions more on topic. You claim, how can I include my research if I found nothing? Well, then, tell us what terms you used when you googled. Not my downvote (I never stopped to wonder so it was interesting), but yes, my closevote.

Comment: Wikipedia, first result in Google by the way, second paragraph: *"When only one mass is present, it is known as a plasmacytoma while **more than one** is known as multiple myeloma"*. Did you actually google "multiple myeloma"? You just asked *"what sort of attempt should I show in this question if I am unable to it by googling?"* in your comment above... well, I believe that googling "multiple myeloma" is what one expects.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I google etymology of multiple myeloma and myeloma vs multiple myeloma.

Comment: Next time just google "multiple myeloma".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> J. Von Rustizky, a Russian pathologist working in the laboratory of Friedrich von Recklinghausen (1833–1910) in Strassburg in 1873, introduced the term “multiple myeloma.” At autopsy, a 47-year-old patient examined had eight separate tumors of bone marrow, which Von Rustizky called “multiple myelomas,” and he noted that the nucleus of the tumor cells was located in the periphery of the cell membrane — a morphology highly suggestive of plasma cells.

[source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/21509678/): Kyle, RA, Steensma, DP (2011) History of multiple myeloma. Recent Results Cancer Res., 183: 3-23

From the same item:

> The most commonly recognized [first documented] case is that of Thomas Alexander McBean, a highly respectable tradesman from London in 1850. Mr. McBean excreted a large amount of protein that was described by Henry Bence Jones in the middle of the 19th century. Jones was a well-known physician and made many contributions to medicine.

The Bence Jones protein is in fact an immunoglobulin light chain. Purified Bence Jones protein were sequenced by FW Putnam, and 
[variations between patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/4166637/) were some of the first clues to the existence of the variable regions of immunoglobulin molecules.

Comment: Hmm, in addition to the information I get from your answer, today I learned a new googling skill, which is to get etymology we should also try History of _________. Thanks.

Comment: Another good strategy would be searching databases like PubMed for "review" articles. These will almost always have "history" sections in the beginning, and even if they're very short, they'll usually have citations to other papers that you should look up—perhaps even the original, as in this case. @JM97